# sorting array based on frequencies in a second array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays in php: $a and $b. Elements of the first array are 26 letters of English alphabet, one by one in the alphabetical order ($a[0]="a", $a[1]="b", etc.). Elements of the second array are frequencies of the corresponding letter from the first array in a long English text ($b[0]=168 is a frequency of letter "a", $b[1]=118 is a frequency of letter "b" etc.).

Objective is to sort elements of the first array according to the frequencies in the second array. Is there a built in function in php, or do I have to implement a sorting algorithm?

Thank you.

Comment: Any attempts or ideas you tried?

Comment: Sure, create a new array $c that is a copy of array $b, sort($c) and create new array $d and find corresponding elements having same frequency in $b and match to $a. But what if two letters share a value of their frequency?

Comment: Don't use `sort` use `asort` or `arsort`(better for descending ordered list)

Answer (score 1):

Since both of your arrays are of fixed length you can easily [combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) them and then do [associative sorting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php)

```
$a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
$b = [500, 600, 90, 120, 90];
$ab = array_combine($a , $b);
arsort($ab);
```